# Pre validate user with LsaLogonUser when offline

Tags: winapi, credential-providers, windows-security

I have a credential provider with MFA codes, and offline MFA codes. Of course, the credential provider is a DLL and is running in a system application under NT Authority\System. I'm not trying to modify the token in any way. I figure if it's running in the logon process, it probably has all the permissions it needs...although that may not be true...

I want to pre-validate user accounts so that we don't force the user to do MFA if he entered a bad username or password. It is annoying when you go through the MFA process, serialize the creds in the interface callback `ICredentialProviderCredential::GetSerializaion` and then it reports bad creds in `ICredentialProverCredential::ReportResults` and you have to repeat the cycle...at least in our current flow.

I am calling `LsaLogonUser` with the logon type as `SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE::Interactive` and the authentication package being `MSV1_0_PACKAGE_NAME`. If the computer is online it always works -- returning `STATUS_NOERROR` for good creds and `STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE` for a failed logon. I have even tried some of the other logon types, thinking maybe `SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE::CachedInteractive` logon type would work...but that returns an unsupported error code for both correct and bad passwords.

If I go offline, Local accounts still pass the `LsaLogonUser` call, however, AzureAD accounts fail. I think I have tested AD joined machines disconnected, but need to go back and test. Right now I'm just trying to solve the AzureAD issue.

I am doing a connect untrusted to populated the first argument of `LsaLogonUser`

... `LsaConnectUntrusted` maybe could be problem???

|  | LsaLoginUser w/ Local Account | LsaLogonUser w/AzureAD account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Online | Success | Success |
| Offline | Success | Failure |

---------------------  Edit Add Info -------------------------

From the outset I knew some of these logon types would be incorrect, but decided to test them all--in for a penny, in for a pound.

| LogonType | Error Msg | NtStatus | NtSubstatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Interactive | The user name or password is incorrect. (1326) | c000006d | 0 |
| Network | The user name or password is incorrect. (1326) | c000006d | 0 |
| Batch | The user name or password is incorrect. (1326) | c000006d | 0 |
| Service | The user name or password is incorrect. (1326) | c000006d | 0 |
| Proxy | A logon request contained an invalid logon type value. (1367) | c000010b) | 0 |
| Unlock | The user name or password is incorrect. (1326) | c000006d | 0 |
| NetworkClearText | The user name or password is incorrect. (1326) | c000006d | 0 |
| NewCredentials | A logon request contained an invalid logon type value. (1367) | c000010b) | 0 |
| RemoteInteractive | The user name or password is incorrect. (1326) | c000006d | 0 |
| CachedInteractive | The request is not supported. (50) | c00000bb | 0 |
| CachedRemoteInteractive | The user name or password is incorrect. (1326) | c000006d | 0 |
| CachedUnlock | A logon request contained an invalid logon type value. (1367) | c000010b) | 0 |

Comment: *LsaConnectUntrusted maybe could be problem???* no of course. you simply have no cashed credentials on local comp. *AzureAD accounts fail.* - why you not include status/substatus code ?!

Comment: @RbMmI will include substatus codes shortly... but, if you are offline and using normal Windows credential provider, somehow it allows an AzureAD user to login. Those creds have to be cached somewhere on the machine to allow that to happen.

Comment: It not used msv1_0 package . Use negotiate pakage

Comment: And anyway - you format serialization by self or got from wrapped provider ?

Comment: When you write cred provider, you must be able debug logonui, winlogon and main - lsass, for view how is going with system built-in providers. ))

Comment: @RbMm for this part, I have my own serialization formatter. But that wasn't the issue. See my answer...

Comment: *I have my own serialization formatter* this is not best solution, if you by fact implement 2FA. you need wrap several built-in providers and use serialization from it. use msv1_0 of course also wrong, need use NEGOSSP_NAME_W ( say in case azure CLOUDAP_NAME_W package is used)

Comment: @RbMm Well, maybe I can learn something, but I don't wrap a provider. In serializing, I use the examples from the SDK. For my pre-logon test, I use a C++-ified version to serialize creds. I'm not wrapping any credentials. For my case, I think I just need the packed Kerb buffer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256840/discussion-between-rbmm-and-joseph-willcoxson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to seem stupid. I have code in places where if it is joined to AzureAD, checks for username, and then substitutes AzureAD for the domain if an email is detected. If the computer is not AD joined, then the default "domain" is WORKGROUP... maybe no bueno...

However, the code path did not substitute AzureAD and so it was failing when disconnected...

HOWEVER... If the machine is connected, `LsaLogonUser()` can verify the creds if the domain is WORKGROUP. To me, that's even stranger...

Bottom line, ensure the domain is set to AzureAD when calling the function when using an AzureAD account.